# Returning a variable from an object within a doubly linked list

Tags: c#, object, doubly-linked-list

*INTRO: Been looking for this answer for a while, haven't found it in the archives despite several searches. Either too simple a problem, or doing something to break the laws of C#*

I'm new to doubly linked lists and they are doing my head in!

I'm having problems getting a doubly linked list to spit out a variable from an object inside the list.

I've tried to simplify the problem in a new file to work it out in my head, but I just can't find the right syntax to Find the variable within the object within the DLL.

I've broken it down to five objects within the DLL, each with a Title.
Now I want to Find an object and return its Title.
But instead: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrgh! what the hell am I doing wrong?

```
namespace ADS
{
public partial class DLL_Generic_Object : Form

{
    public DLL_Generic_Object()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //create class

    public partial class Weapon
    {
        string Title;

        public Weapon(string title)
        {                
            this.Title = title;    
        }

    }

    //create objects;

    Weapon object1 = new Weapon("Revolver");
    Weapon object2 = new Weapon("Candlestick");
    Weapon object3 = new Weapon("Lead Pipe");
    Weapon object4 = new Weapon("Rope");
    Weapon object5 = new Weapon("Knife");

    public class Structures
    {
        public string getTitle(LinkedList<Object> nameofDLL)
        {
            string gotTitle = "How do I Find the Title variable of an Object in the DLL?";

            return gotTitle;
        }
    }

    //create an object Doubly Linked List
    LinkedList<object> weapons = new LinkedList<object>();

    private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintNodes(weapons); //This will show the DLL is empty.

        //Add nodes to the list
        weapons.AddFirst(object1); //add a node to the front of the list

        //Add a node after a specific node.
        weapons.AddAfter(weapons.Find(object1), object2);
        weapons.AddAfter(weapons.Find(object2), object4);

        //Add a node before a specific node.
        weapons.AddBefore(weapons.Find(object4), object3);

        //Add a node to the end of the list
        weapons.AddLast(object5);

        PrintNodes(weapons); // This will show the DLL has 5 Nodes.

    // Find the value of a node
    }
    public string FindTitle(LinkedList<Object> nameofDLL)
    {
        // initialise a Structures class
        Structures structure = new Structures();

        // Find the value of a node
        string value = structure.getTitle(weapons) + "\r\n";

        return value;
    }
    public void PrintNodes(LinkedList<object> values)
    {
        if (values.Count != 0) //check if there are any nodes in the list
        {
            txtOutput.Text += "The number of nodes is: " + values.Count.ToString() + "\r\n";

            txtOutput.Text += FindTitle(weapons);

        }

        else
            txtOutput.Text += "The Doubly Linked List is empty" + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use `object` when you don't know the type of the objects in the list. Why isn't this a `LinkedList<Weapon>` if the list only contains weapons?

Comment: Fair call. I was trying to keep it somewhat generic, but happy to change the LinkedList to <Weapon> if it works!

Comment: It hasn't falling over by changing to <Weapon>, so thanks for that. But I still need to know HOW to Return the Title value from within the DLL. I don't understand where I'm going wrong...

Comment: What do you mean by "Get the title of the DLL"? The list doesn't have one singular "title". You have a list of `Weapon` objects, each with its own title. I don't understand what it is you are trying to do here.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to return a Title from an object within DLL. So for example, I want to say "What is the title of the second object?" (which in this instance would "Candlestick") What is the correct syntax for Returning that Title?

Comment: You are trying to get an object from the linked list at an index, which is treating it like a regular list. If you really need this functionality, you need to ask yourself if a linked list is really what you need.

Comment: Ha ha! I wouldn't choose a DLL. It's part of my course. I don't understand their relevance, but I'm just following orders. They're asking to put objects inside DLLs and then return values from within those objects. I've simplified the task down to these objects with just one variable so I can understand the process, but I keep hitting this roadblock.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't talking about iterating over the list as a whole using either a `foreach` or a `while`? Requiring that you retrieve the specific element at an index from a linked list is very odd.

Comment: The actual assignment requires printing out the list of nodes from within the DLL, but before I can do that, I need to work out how to print a single value from an object! I can put in all the foreaches and whiles I like, but if I can access the information, they won't do much good.

Comment: Try something like this: `public string FindTitle(LinkedList<Weapon> nameofDLL) { return String.Join(", ", nameofDLL.Select(x => x.Title)); }`

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot.

Comment: @ChadLockwood - Who are saying "Thanks" to? If it's me then you to `@` notify me when you reply.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be approaching the problem from the wrong angle. It is not advisable to try and get the element at a particular index of a Doubly Linked List, because that is not what it is designed for. The purpose of using a DLL is having a collection that can be navigated using the elements within the list instead of with the list itself. For example, if you get a given node from some source, you can use the `Next` and `Previous` properties to navigate the list.

If the goal is to traverse the entire list, there are two general ways to do it. First and most straightforward is the `foreach` method:

```
foreach (var node in linkedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Title);
}
```

The second method is using a `while`. This method is slightly more complex, but it more clearly demonstrates the behavior and intentions of a LinkedList:

```
var node = linkedList.First;
while (node != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Value.Title);
    node = node.Next;
}
```

If you absolutely *need* to get the element at a particular index, it is possible, and the simplest way is to use the `ElementAt` or `ElementAtOrDefault` LINQ methods. The difference between them being that, if the given index is outside the bounds of the list, `ElementAt` will throw an exception whereas `ElementAtOrDefault` will return the default value for the given type (in the case of your `Weapon` type, the default value is `null`) - which method you should choose depends on which behavior you prefer for your particular implementation:

```
int idx = 5;
var elem = linkedList.ElementAt(idx);
```

But as I said in my comment, the above method basically treats the LinkedList as a regular List, so if you need to do this frequently then you need to ask yourself why you aren't just using a List.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Abion47. That's helped immensely.

Comment: @ChadLockwood If this answers your question, please be sure to mark it as the answer.